# Issue react draft wysiwyg package in React Hooks project unable to integrate

Tags: react-hooks, wysiwyg, react-hook-form

I am working on a project where I am trying to integrate react draft WYSIWYG in my React Hooks project. I am facing an issue while integrating
I initialize

```
var editorState = EditorState.createEmpty();
const [description, setDescription] = React.useState(editorState);

const setEditorState = (editorState) => {
  console.log('editorState', editorState)
  setDescription(editorState)
}

return (
  <Editor
    editorState={description}
    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
    editorClassName="editorClassName"
    onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
  />
);
```

**console log print this:**

> _immutable: Record {_map: Map, __ownerID: undefined}}
> but i cannot show editor value in console or
> in textbox whenever i  am typing anything inside the editor box following error

**value show in the text box**

> Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good start to get `react-draft-wysiwyg` working with `react-hook-form`.

You've to use `useController` or `Controller` and map the `value`, `onChange` properties.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hermann-6wi9o?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Hey There !! We have tried to follow what you have suggested but in the codesandbox link that you have provided, when we ran the code we could not see the value rather in many places we saw "undefied". Line number: 14. Now we have added one more line top print the data being submitted on to our console console.log("editor value"+data);. But that gave 
editor value[object Object] . Can't figure out whats happening and literally beaking head to find a solution as i am under severe pressure of project delivery and no solution that i am getting is working OK for me.Request to please help earliest

Comment: Please help earnest request. I am literally stuck with integrating react-draft-wysiwyg with react-hook-form and not getting any way outs.

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox with your issue please ?

Comment: You can use this 
    https://codesandbox.io/s/editor-pv9ui?file=/src/App.js